# Command run by cron is not writing to terminal

Tags: bash, unix, cron

In my cron tab file, I have

```
* * * * * /Users/ajgauravdeep/test.sh
```

which looks like

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 
  3 /bin/echo "Downloading builds"
  4 #~luna/bin/mountebuild
  5 
  6 #sleep 10
  7 
  8 ##############---------Variables---------##############
  9 
 10 fileWithBuildPath="/tmp/process.tmp.file.txt"
 11 skihillDir="xyz"
 12 lastBuild=`/bin/cat $fileWithBuildPath`
 13 curBuild=`/usr/bin/readlink -n $skihillDir/x`
 14 
 15 ##############---------Variables---------##############
 16 
 17 /bin/echo lastbuild is $lastBuild
 18 
 19 if [ "$curBuild" != "$lastBuild" ]; then
 20         lastBuild=$curBuild
 21         /bin/echo We have a new build :$curBuild
 22         /bin/rm $fileWithBuildPath
 23         /bin/echo "$lastBuild" > $fileWithBuildPath
 24 fi
```

I don't see any output coming every minute on screen but when I have

```
* * * * * /Users/ajgauravdeep/test.sh > <some file>
```

I see that file is populated. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you search stackoverflow for this, you might find lots of related questions. When a `cron` job runs, it doesn't have the same shell PATH settings as your login shell. You need to make sure (*e.g.*, by explicitly setting the path in the `crontab`, for example) that the `cron` job has access to all of the desired commands.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did that  too. /bin/echo, /bin/cat but same problem, for all the commands i have in this script

Comment: Where does `CommandResultsMake.py` come from? Your `test.sh` script doesn't call any other external scripts. How are you making a `cron` job with the `test.sh` script?

Comment: Please read question again. It has been modified

Comment: If you want to see output on a terminal, why is this set up as a `cron` job? The purpose of a `cron` job is to have it run at regular intervals when you're not around. One alternative would be to have it output to a file somewhere and then, in a terminal, do `tail -f output_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs run by `cron` are not connected to any terminal, much less your current terminal.  You can't expect to a job with `cron` to write to a terminal.

Comment: oh no wonder... is there any way that i can out the output to current terminal?

Comment: How do you determine your current terminal?  On a windowing system, you may have several terminals (pseudo-terminals) open.  In theory, there could be other users on the system; you don't want to write to their terminals.  Perhaps you could arrange to look for terminals you own: `find /dev -user you -name 'tty*'` or something similar to accommodate the terminal names on your system, and then arrange to send the output from your command via `tee` to all those terminals.